# Can one update/set TFS Next ChangesetId?

Tags: tfs, changeset, tfs-2015

Currently running TFS2010, have TFS2015 on a fresh install, new machine.  The plan is to migrate collections and projects over that we want via VS (repointing to the new server, checking in, etc.)  Naturally, the next changesetid on the TFS2015 machine will be 1.  I was hoping there was a way to set the next id to continue the sequence from the TFS2010 machine.

On the other hand, is a data migration from TFS2010 -> TFS2015 a better or smarter option?

I've looked all over for some simple way to set the next changeset id, but to no avail. It may that it's not possible.

Comment: Did you only need TFS2015, or you want to keep both TFS2010 and TFS2015?

Comment: TFS2010 would go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use TFS2015. I think you need **Upgrade**. This option will keep your data. And you don't have to set the ChangesetId. It will continue the sequence from the TFS2010 machine automatically.
As Daniel mentioned, you should also pay attention to the [Requirements and compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements) for TFS 2015.

For your situation:

1. Back up your old SQL(SQL2008) of TFS2010, restore it to the new SQL
   for TFS2015(should be SQL2012 or SQL2014)
2. Uninstall the AT of TFS2015 on the new machine.
3. Reinstall it and select Upgrade in TFS configuration center. 
   Seclect the new DT during the Wizard.It will automatically upgrades the database to meet TFS2015. (Since you have configurated , there may be conflicts)

For migration, it's a data lose option. By the way , [below info](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) may be useful for you:

> **Migration** - For this project, and for TFS in general, we use the term
>   "migration" to refer to moving data between two TFS server instances.
>   Migration is done through the APIs of TFS by using external tools, and
>   is **a lossy data transfer**.
>
> **Upgrade** - We would define "upgrade" as the fully supported, in-the-box
>   process of changing to the next version of TFS (e.g. upgrading from
>   TFS 2010 to TFS 2015). Upgrades are done at the database level, and
>   are full fidelity, meaning there is **no data loss**.

Comment: Keep in mind that the supported OS versions and SQL server versions have **drastically** changed since TFS2010, as have Sharepoint requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the requirements.  No Sharepoint or Project Server, just a straight move/upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You should migrate from TFS2010 to TFS2015 by following these steps:"

1. TFS2010: Detach collection
2. TFS2010: Back-up SQL database of the collection
3. TFS2015: Restore SQL database from #2
4. TFS2015: Attach collection

In this way you'll migrate everything: source code with history, work items with history.

The [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) tool doesn't have support for TFS2015.